# How to draw text with characters rendered in reverse order in a Godot game?

Tags: godot, fonts

I need to have some text showing up in my Godot game in a way that each character overlaps the character directly to its right, like so:

```
     -- ---    -- --
   /  /     \ |  |  |
  /  /       \|  |  |
 /  /  /---\  \  |   ----
/  /  /  \  \  \ |       |
-- --     -- -- - -------
```

Using a BMFont (.fnt) in a `Label` node with the values of `xadvance` specified in the font smaller than the characters width I get this:

```
     -- ---    -- --
   /  /     \ |  |  |
  /  /       \|  |  |
 /  /  /---\  |  |   ----
/  /  /  \  \ |  |       |
-- --     -- -- - -------
```

What approach can I use to still be able to use my .fnt font and also store the text with the characters in their natural order, as it would be stored for using with a normal `Label` or `Button` control? Which would help for language localization purposes.

Comment: Hack the source, draw in the opposite order? https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/scene/gui/label.cpp#L327

Comment: @hangar it seems it could be accomplished very easily making a few changes to that segment of the source code. I'll be more than happy to award you the bounty if you post an answer with the corresponding snippet of code.